# Internet Explorer file upload fails mime-type check

Tags: php, internet-explorer, file-upload, mime-types

I have cobbled together some scripts from various internet sources to get a form working. I have run into an issue that I can't solve. The form I created allows the user to submit their data in fields, plus an image attachment (validation: .EPS or .JPG format).

The script works fine in Firefox and Safari, but not in Internet Explorer. In IE, whether or not you attach an image of the correct type, it returns the error for incorrect file type. So for some reason it seems IE is not validating the file type as the PHP is asking it to do.

```
<?php
/* ....
   snip
   .... */
      $filetype=$_FILES["prosp_client_logo"]["type"];
/* ....
   snip
   .... */
      elseif($filetype=="application/postscript" or $filetype=="image/jpg" or $filetype=="image/jpeg") {
/* ....
   snip
   .... */
?>
```

Please let me know if you need any clarification.

Comment: Hi, There's a lot of code in there that doesnt deal with the problem you're describing. Could you cut it down to just the code that processes the uploaded file and returns the error (and double check that the error occurs with your trimmed code).

Comment: This isn't what you asked, but someone is certain to tell you and it might as well be me.  You should read up on SQL injection attacks, to which your script is vulnerable. Whenever you pass a variable into a SQL query, you should first pass it through `mysql_real_escape_string()`.  Examples in your code would be ` $newentry="INSERT INTO TestTable (...) VALUES ('NULL','$user_name', '$user_email', '$filename')";`  First you should call `$user_name = mysql_real_escape_string($user_name);` etc. on all those variables.

Comment: Thank you, I had a feeling my script was not secure. I will try inserting that code.

Comment: @preinheimer - I had already trimmed it considerably (it's a much longer form), but left in a lot because I wasn't sure where I could have been tripping up IE. I know it's not very well structured. I will try to trim further, but anyone with suggestions on what I have here are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: @BrianChicago76: I've done the trimming for you. :)

Comment: @jnpcl - Thanks for all your help. You're a scholar and a gentleman.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php#75932

> **Richard Davey rich at corephp dot co dot uk  22-Jun-2007 12:05**
>   [...] you may be inclined to validate an update based on its reported mime-type from the $_FILES array. However be careful with this - it is set by the *browser*, not by PHP or the web server, and browsers are not consistent (what's new?!)

IE will send its own `mime-type` (based on its filesystem association) for the attachment, which can often be different than what you're expecting in your code. This data can also be spoofed, so it's best not to trust what the browser says about the file's `mime-type`.

**Also:**

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php#53133

> **keith at phpdiary dot org  24-May-2005 11:14**
>   [...] My best bet would be for you to check the extension of the file and using exif_imagetype() to check for valid images.  Many people have suggested the use of getimagesize() which returns an array if the file is indeed an image and false otherwise, but exif_imagetype() is much faster. (the manual says it so)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Can you provide a string of code that does that, or can I find how to do it on PHP.net?

Comment: @BrianChicago76: Look at the PHP.net manual entries for `getimagesize()` (or, preferably) `exif_imagetype()`

Comment: And if you could provide me with a general idea of where to insert that validation i.e. exif_imagetype(), and what code I should remove, that would be a huge help. As I said, I am a huge n00b. Thanks, fellas.

Comment: @jnpcl: exif_imagetype() does not seem to have postscript (EPS) as an option under imagetype constants. Is there a way to validate if the image file is an EPS? Thanks.

Comment: @BrianChicago76: It looks like the best method is to install the [FileInfo](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php) PECL extension and use its functions. All other methods seem to be deprecated, or require running shell commands.

Comment: @jnpcl Did some digging. Is FileInfo deprecated as well? http://pecl.php.net/package/Fileinfo

Comment: @BrianChicago76: I don't believe so. You may be looking at an older implementation.